# psycopg3 pool: all connections getting lost instantly after long idle time

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psycopg3

If it's a standalone persistant connection, I have no problem, connection lasts for hours.
If I use psycopg(3) Connection pool, I make make requests, first requests are ok and my pool size stays at 5, at one point pool size decreases and I get a Pool Timeout when client makes a new request.
Then I tried: start pool, do not request anything, just wait. After some time (around 1h) I look at postgresql (pg_stat_activity), I have 5 idle (=pool size) connections. Then I make a request from client, and all connections vanish at same time (I can see it from pg_stat_activity) and Pool Timeout, and situation is stuck.

I also tried to decrease max_timeout to 900 but still same issue.

```
def init_pool(self, min_cnx=5):
    cnx_str = f"host={DB_HOST} port={DB_PORT} dbname={DB_NAME} user={DB_USERNAME} password={DB_USERPWD}"
    self.pool = ConnectionPool(conninfo=cnx_str, min_size=min_cnx, open=True, check=ConnectionPool.check_connection)

def query(self, q, dbv=None, debug=False) -> list:

    print("pool size: ", len(self.pool._pool))
    print("pool stats before: ", self.pool.get_stats())

    with self.pool.connection() as cnx:

        if cnx.closed:
            self.pool.check()
            raise ConnectionError("ERROR: PostgreSQL cnx from pool is closed.")

        cnx.autocommit = True
        cnx.row_factory = self.row_factory

        with psycopg.ClientCursor(cnx) as rdc:
            rdc.execute(q, dbv) if dbv else rdc.execute(q)

            if debug and rdc._query:
                print(rdc._query.query)

            if rdc.description:
                data = rdc.fetchall()
            else:
                data = []

        print("pool stats after query: ", self.pool.get_stats())
    print("pool stats after: ", self.pool.get_stats())
    return data
```

And logs:

```
[pid: 236344|app: 0|req: 26/26] () {56 vars in 1083 bytes} [Mon Feb  5 11:41:56 2024] POST /v1/user => generated 933 bytes in 
109 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 8 headers in 749 bytes (1 switches on core 0)                                                                                                                                         
pool size:  3                                                                                                                               
pool stats before:  {'connections_num': 5, 'requests_num': 3, 'requests_queued': 1, 'connections_ms': 268, 'requests_wait_ms': 34, 'usage_ms
': 34, 'pool_min': 5, 'pool_max': 5, 'pool_size': 5, 'pool_available': 3, 'requests_waiting': 0}                                            
pool stats after query:  {'connections_num': 5, 'requests_num': 4, 'requests_queued': 1, 'connections_ms': 268, 'requests_wait_ms': 34, 'usa
ge_ms': 34, 'pool_min': 5, 'pool_max': 5, 'pool_size': 5, 'pool_available': 2, 'requests_waiting': 0}                                       
pool stats after:  {'connections_num': 5, 'requests_num': 4, 'requests_queued': 1, 'connections_ms': 268, 'requests_wait_ms': 34, 'usage_ms'
: 49, 'pool_min': 5, 'pool_max': 5, 'pool_size': 5, 'pool_available': 2, 'requests_waiting': 0}                                             
[pid: 236344|app: 0|req: 28/28] () {56 vars in 1087 bytes} [Mon Feb  5 11:41:58 2024] POST /v1/iobjs => generated 4788 bytes i
n 29 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 302 bytes (1 switches on core 0)                                                                     
[pid: 236344|app: 0|req: 29/29] () {54 vars in 816 bytes} [Mon Feb  5 11:42:05 2024] OPTIONS /v1/user/quit => generated 0 byte
s in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 307 bytes (0 switches on core 0)                                                                                                                                                              
pool size:  0   
pool stats before:  {'connections_num': 5, 'requests_num': 6, 'requests_queued': 1, 'connections_ms': 268, 'requests_wait_ms': 34, 'usage_ms
': 62, 'pool_min': 5, 'pool_max': 5, 'pool_size': 5, 'pool_available': 0, 'requests_waiting': 0}                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                          
  File "/var/srvr/log.py", line 68, in process
    self.db.query(
  File "/var/srvr/pg3p.py", line 71, in query
    with self.pool.connection() as cnx:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/srvr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/psycopg_pool/pool.py", line 170, in connection
    conn = self.getconn(timeout=timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/var/srvr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/psycopg_pool/pool.py", line 204, in getconn
    raise PoolTimeout(
psycopg_pool.PoolTimeout: couldn't get a connection after 30.00 sec  
pool size:  0  
pool stats before:  {'connections_num': 5, 'requests_num': 7, 'requests_queued': 2, 'connections_ms': 268, 'requests_wait_ms': 30035, 'usage
_ms': 62, 'requests_errors': 1, 'pool_min': 5, 'pool_max': 5, 'pool_size': 5, 'pool_available': 0, 'requests_waiting': 1}
```

EDIT:
I switched back to 1 single persistant connection, it is very stable (days). Then following advices in comments, I moved back to pool with min_size=10 and max_size=20.
No change in behaviour: pool is loosing connections without trying to initiate new ones to replace the lost (also tried 20 and 50 min/max, no difference)

```
pool stats after:  {'connections_num': 11, 'requests_num': 34, 'requests_queued': 1, 'connections_ms': 641, 'requests_wait_ms': 37, 'usage_m s': 67, 'pool_min': 10, 'pool_max': 20, 'pool_size': 11, 'pool_available': 5, 'requests_waiting': 0}
[pid: 282017|app: 0|req: 39/39]  () {56 vars in 1087 bytes}[Thu Feb  8 11:02:17 2024] POST /v1/iobjs => generated 30081 bytes  in 10 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 303 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
pool size:  5                                                         
pool stats before:  {'connections_num': 11, 'requests_num': 34, 'requests_queued': 1, 'connections_ms': 641, 'requests_wait_ms': 37, 'usage_ ms': 67, 'pool_min': 10, 'pool_max': 20, 'pool_size': 11, 'pool_available': 5, 'requests_waiting': 0}                          
pool stats after query:  {'connections_num': 11, 'requests_num': 35, 'requests_queued': 1, 'connections_ms': 641, 'requests_wait_ms': 37, 'u sage_ms': 67, 'connections_lost': 1, 'pool_min': 10, 'pool_max': 20, 'pool_size': 11, 'pool_available': 3, 'requests_waiting': 0}       
pool stats after:  {'connections_num': 11, 'requests_num': 35, 'requests_queued': 1, 'connections_ms': 641, 'requests_wait_ms': 37, 'usage_m s': 70, 'connections_lost': 1, 'pool_min': 10, 'pool_max': 20, 'pool_size': 11, 'pool_available': 3, 'requests_waiting': 0}       
[pid: 282017|app: 0|req: 40/40]  () {56 vars in 1087 bytes} [Thu Feb  8 11:02:17 2024] POST /v1/iobjs => generated 4788 bytes i n 5 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 302 bytes (1 switches on core 0)   
[pid: 282017|app: 0|req: 41/41]  () {54 vars in 808 bytes} [Thu Feb  8 11:02:26 2024] OPTIONS /v1/iobjs => generated 0 bytes in  0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 307 bytes (0 switches on core 0)   
[pid: 282017|app: 0|req: 42/42]  () {54 vars in 814 bytes} [Thu Feb  8 11:02:26 2024] OPTIONS /v1/settings => generated 0 bytes  in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 307 bytes (0 switches on core 0)                                                                  
pool size:  3                                                          
pool stats before:  {'connections_num': 11, 'requests_num': 35, 'requests_queued': 1, 'connections_ms': 641, 'requests_wait_ms': 37, 'usage_ ms': 70, 'connections_lost': 1, 'pool_min': 10, 'pool_max': 20, 'pool_size': 11, 'pool_available': 3, 'requests_waiting': 0}       
pool stats after query:  {'connections_num': 11, 'requests_num': 36, 'requests_queued': 1, 'connections_ms': 641, 'requests_wait_ms': 37, 'u sage_ms': 70, 'connections_lost': 1, 'pool_min': 10, 'pool_max': 20, 'pool_size': 11, 'pool_available': 2, 'requests_waiting': 0}       
pool stats after:  {'connections_num': 11, 'requests_num': 36, 'requests_queued': 1, 'connections_ms': 641, 'requests_wait_ms': 37, 'usage_m s': 73, 'connections_lost': 1, 'pool_min': 10, 'pool_max': 20, 'pool_size': 11, 'pool_available': 2, 'requests_waiting': 0}       
[pid: 282017|app: 0|req: 43/43]  () {56 vars in 1087 bytes} [Thu Feb  8 11:02:26 2024] POST /v1/iobjs => generated 4788 bytes i n 6 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 302 bytes (1 switches on core 0)   
Traceback (most recent call last):                                     File "main.py", line 326, in v1_settings                              

    row = db.query_row(                                                                                                                     
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and postgresql logs (debug3) show nothing special (AFAIU):

```
2024-02-08 11:02:17.075 CET [282007] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 2 callbacks to make                                                
2024-02-08 11:02:17.075 CET [282007] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  exit(0)                                                                          
2024-02-08 11:02:17.075 CET [282007] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make                            
2024-02-08 11:02:17.075 CET [282007] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make                                
2024-02-08 11:02:17.075 CET [282007] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make                                               
2024-02-08 11:02:17.079 CET [281970] DEBUG:  server process (PID 282007) exited with exit code 0                                            
2024-02-08 11:02:26.183 CET [282006] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 4 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make                             
2024-02-08 11:02:26.183 CET [282006] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 6 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make                                 
2024-02-08 11:02:26.183 CET [282006] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 2 callbacks to make                                                
2024-02-08 11:02:26.183 CET [282006] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  exit(0)                                                                          
2024-02-08 11:02:26.183 CET [282006] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make                            
2024-02-08 11:02:26.183 CET [282006] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make                                
2024-02-08 11:02:26.183 CET [282006] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make                                               
2024-02-08 11:02:26.188 CET [282009] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 4 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make                             
2024-02-08 11:02:26.189 CET [282009] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 6 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2024-02-08 11:02:26.189 CET [282009] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 2 callbacks to make
2024-02-08 11:02:26.189 CET [282009] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  exit(0)
2024-02-08 11:02:26.189 CET [282009] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2024-02-08 11:02:26.189 CET [282009] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2024-02-08 11:02:26.189 CET [282009] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2024-02-08 11:02:26.189 CET [281970] DEBUG:  server process (PID 282006) exited with exit code 0
2024-02-08 11:02:26.191 CET [282011] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 4 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2024-02-08 11:02:26.191 CET [282011] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 6 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2024-02-08 11:02:26.191 CET [282011] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 2 callbacks to make
2024-02-08 11:02:26.192 CET [282011] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  exit(0)
2024-02-08 11:02:26.192 CET [282011] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2024-02-08 11:02:26.192 CET [282011] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2024-02-08 11:02:26.192 CET [282011] pguser@maindb DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2024-02-08 11:02:26.193 CET [281970] DEBUG:  server process (PID 282009) exited with exit code 0
2024-02-08 11:02:26.194 CET [281970] DEBUG:  server process (PID 282011) exited with exit code 0
2024-02-08 11:02:33.979 CET [281970] DEBUG:  postmaster received pmsignal signal
2024-02-08 11:02:33.983 CET [282844] DEBUG:  InitPostgres
2024-02-08 11:02:33.985 CET [282844] DEBUG:  autovacuum: processing database "template1"
```

query_row() being same as query():

```
def query_row(self, q, dbv=None, debug=False):

    with self.pool.connection() as cnx:
        cnx.autocommit = True
        cnx.row_factory = self.row_factory

        with psycopg.ClientCursor(cnx) as c:
            c.execute(q, dbv) if dbv else c.execute(q)

            if debug and c._query:
                print(c._query.query)

            if c.rowcount == 1:
                return c.fetchone()
            else:
                return None
```

Comment: What I am seeing is a timeout error due to the pool being full per `psycopg_pool.PoolTimeout: couldn't get a connection after 30.00 sec` due to `'connections_num': 5, 'requests_num': 7, 'requests_queued': 2`

Comment: How are you using `def query()` to generate multiple queries?

Comment: I would test this for myself, but the example is not complete enough to do so.  The defined functions are never called, and presumably need to be wrapped in some missing class, not bare.  Are any imports needed, besides psycopg itself?

Comment: @jjanes yes the functons are in a class PG, but only a wrapper... at uwsgi start, each worker create a PG instanstance and pg.init_pool() is called. Then when an endpoint is called (I use bottle), pg.query() is called with the corresponding SQL query (q parameter in the PG.query signature)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, yes eventually pg.query() is called multiple times for each endpoint (application is an API) but it shouldn't have impact. postgresql server and bottle runtime are on the same server and SQL queries are trivials (<1ms)

Comment: there is something that comes to my mind: I have 2 uwsgi workers running, so I should see 10 idle connections from postgresql, and I only see 5. I'll dig into why.

Comment: You are missing the point, it is not about the time the query takes it is about the pool filling up to it's limit of 5 connections and a time out for new connections above the existing 5. In other words the pool is not recycling connections and you don't have `max` set above the `min` to allow the pool to grow.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, ok I thought that SQL queries were so fast that connection would be returned to the pool before another .query() call would tap the pool to get a connection, but indeed it might not be fast enough. I'll try to set a max to 20 to see. But I still don't understand why connections just vanished together without pool trying to replace them.

Comment: When you run the code `tail` the Postgres log to see what is actually happening at the server.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I made more tests and logs (see edit), still in the dark...

Comment: 1) The Postgres log is not useful as it has too much detail(DEBUG).  Set back to normal  level(WARNING) and make sure `log_connections` and `log_disconnections` are `on`. You are looking for just that, when connections are made and torn done. 2) Where is `ow = db.query_row(` coming from in the traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connection logs from postgresql gave a hint: SSL error before all connection going dust:

```
2024-02-09 10:38:05.627 CET [297036] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time                                                                        
2024-02-09 10:38:05.739 CET [297036] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 2 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0. 103 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.112 s; sync files=2, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=1 kB, estimate=1 kB; lsn=0/1C4BB70, redo lsn=0/1C4BB38
2024-02-09 10:46:46.488 CET [297518] user@db LOG:  SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac
2024-02-09 10:46:46.489 CET [297518] user@db LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2024-02-09 10:46:46.489 CET [297518] user@db LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:10:00.165 user=user database=db host=127.0.0.1 port=56266
2024-02-09 12:18:21.905 CET [297528] user@db LOG:  disconnection: session time: 1:41:35.416 user=user database=db host=127.0.0.1 port=56356
2024-02-09 12:18:21.909 CET [297519] user@db LOG:  disconnection: session time: 1:41:35.587 user=user database=db host=127.0.0.1 port=56276
2024-02-09 12:18:24.998 CET [297520] user@db LOG:  disconnect103 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.112 s; sync files=2, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=1 kB, estimate=1 kB; lsn=0/1C4BB70, redo lsn=0/1C4BB38
2024-02-09 12:18:25.033 CET [297521] user@db LOG:  disconnection: session time: 1:41:38.672 user=user database=db host=127.0.0.1 port=56296
2024-02-09 12:18:33.726 CET [297522] user@db LOG:  disconnection: session time: 1:41:47.360 user=user database=db host=127.0.0.1 port=56302
2024-02-09 12:18:33.739 CET [297523] user@db LOG:  disconnection: session time: 1:41:47.372 user=user database=db host=127.0.0.1 port=56308
2024-02-09 12:18:33.745 CET [297524] user@db LOG:  disconnection: session time: 1:41:47.316 user=user database=db host=127.0.0.1 port=56310
2024-02-09 12:18:33.760 CET [297525] user@db LOG:  disconnection: session time: 1:41:47.325 user=user database=db host=127.0.0.1 port=56320
2024-02-09 12:18:35.793 CET [297526] user@db LOG:  disconnection: session time: 1:41:49.353 user=user database=db host=127.0.0.1 port=56336
2024-02-09 12:18:35.847 CET [297527] user@db LOG:  disconnection: session time: 1:41:49.365 user=user database=db host=127.0.0.1 port=56340
```

Reason of this SSL error comes from uwsgi default behaviour: if you have 2 workers, at init a context is created (variables initialized, among them Pool and connections) then workers share memory. It results the classical case where connections are shared between 2 workers.
At one point in time, it is causing a SSL inconsistency, resulting in mass-closing.
Solution was to instruct, with `lazy-apps=true`, uwsgi to create each worker with its own context.